# Is there any way to exclude results of a query based on its own results?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a normal SELECT call like (well, this is really simplified for the question):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_b = "X" and column_c = "Y"
```

but I also want to exclude the results where column_a (the primary key) matches column_k of any other matched results.  I think I can do it something like (I haven't tested this because it's not the way I want to do it)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_b = "X" AND column_c = "Y"
    AND column_k NOT IN
    (SELECT column_a FROM table WHERE column_b = "X" AND column_c = "Y")
```

Being a big advocate of DRY programming, I don't like that this method pretty much repeats the entire SELECT call, if it even works.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is to create a view with your basic logic:

```
CREATE VIEW myview
AS 
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  column_b = 'X' AND column_c = 'Y'
```

Now, this logic can be reused:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   myview
WHERE  column_a NOT IN (SELECT column_k FROM myview)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work in my case.  All the inputted data ("X" and "Y" in my example SELECT) will be coming from user searches, so I would have to do a lot of sanitization/PDO Prepare with views... but I'll look into it.  I've also never created a TEMP view (which I'd have to use for this), but maybe. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  The table will have to have 2 instances in the query somewhere.  You just need to make sure it is utilizing indexes and not doing a full table scan to accomplish the compare.  Another approach would be a not exists instead of in.  I know that performs better in MySQL.  Not sure if it makes a difference with sql lite.

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 WHERE column_b = "X" AND column_c = "Y"
    AND column_a NOT Exists
    (SELECT NULL FROM table t2 WHERE column_b = "X" AND column_c = "Y"  and t2.column_k = t1.column_a)
```